# "0x80004005: Unspecified error" when renaming folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, rename

### Setup

I've just installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.  The operating system is installed on an [80GB Intel X-25M](http://www.intel.com/design/flash/nand/mainstream/index.htm).  I have a secondary [500GB Barracuda 7200.12](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=c501895c8ccce110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD) to be used for storage.  This second drive is mounted as 'G'.

[image: disk management console]

### Problem

I'm getting an error whenever I try to rename a folder within this drive.  The error says:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from renaming the folder.  If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error

[image: error message screenshot]

Clicking the "Try Again" button gets past the error, and correctly renames the folder.

If I create a folder and leave it's name as "New Folder", then I don't see an error.  I'm also able to manipulate files however I want without seeing an error.

### Things I've Tried

- Changing permissions on the drive
- Reformatting the drive.  I've tried using both a "Basic", "GPT" and "Dynamic" partition table.
- Checking the drive for errors using Microsoft tools

Comment: AFAIK Windows should be able to handle a GUID Partition Table (GPT) as well as a traditional MBR partition table.

Comment: I've now tried all three types of partition tables, but my problems continue. I'll keep looking for other options.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is gone, but I don't know what I did to fix it.  I was experimenting with 'Basic', 'Dynamic', and 'GPT' partition tables and noticed that the error wasn't occurring any more.

At first I thought I had stumbled upon a good combination of settings.  I then recreated my original MBR partition table with a Basic partition on it as a final test.  There's still no problem.